# Haskell Yesod and writeFile

Tags: json, haskell, yesod

I am trying to learn Yesod and trying to implement a simple REST app where everytime a I get a *GET* request I write something to a file. Right now I have the following handler function:

```
getTestR =
  do
    return $ writeFile "test.txt" "Just something"
    return $ object ["result" .= "Ok"]
```

What I was expecting is that the file `test.txt` would be created and I would obtain a JSON with `{result=Ok}`. However, I am obtaining the JSON, but the file is not being created.

I guess the `writeFile` is not being evaluated because of the lazy evaluation, but I have no idea how to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: first remove the `return` and see what the compiler tells you about the type ... then look for `liftIO` ;)

Comment: `return` here wraps the `IO` computation into your Yesod-monad and then just ignores it - you can try this in simple `IO` do - if you open up `GHCi` and input `return (print "Hello")` you will see ... *nothing* - `IO (IO ())` is just ignored

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot for your answer, I didn't have the return, put I added it because of this:

Comment: @Carsten: I am getting this:   Couldn't match expected type `HandlerT Calculator IO a0' with actual type `IO ()'
        In a stmt of a 'do' block: writeFile "test.txt" "Just something"
        In the expression:
          do {  writeFile "test.txt" "Just something";
               return $ object ["result" .= "Ok"] }

Comment: have you tried `liftIO $ writeFile ...`?

Comment: @Carsten. That did the trick! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `liftIO`:

```
getTestR =
  do
    liftIO $ writeFile "test.txt" "Just something"
    return $ object ["result" .= "Ok"]
```